# Why does my Win32 application nearly crash my computer when I try rendering OpenGL to a static control?

Tags: winapi, opengl, rendering

I have a Win32 application with a static control that I want to render to using OpenGL. The problem is when I run the application, my computer comes to a screeching halt and more than once now I've had to hard-reboot it. It takes less than a second and it's really brutal. Most of my code here is ripped off of the internet or from my OpenGL bluebook. I have tried doing this several other ways, some with the same results and some with different but no more desirable results, including making the static control owner-draw, subclassing the static control, and just rendering to the control in it's parent's (the main window's) WM_PAINT message. I'm not even rendering any geometry yet, I just want to see the clear color. Most if not all of the resources I've found online either don't cover rendering to a control or using MFC instead of native Win32 API calls.

I have determined that it only happens because I am calling glClear(). If I don't call it, I don't experience the slow down, but I also don't see anything in my static control.

Some more information:

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- Windows SDK v7.0a
- GLEW 1.7
- nVidia Quadro 1600M with the latest drivers
- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Here is my code:

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <gl\wglew.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"
//#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#define IDC_THE_BUTTON 9001

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

struct GlobalSection
{
    HINSTANCE   app;
    HWND        wnd;
    HWND        button;
    HWND        panel;
    HWND        text;
    HGLRC       glrc;
    HDC         fdc;
} g;

bool initWindow(int cmdShow);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
void Init(HWND wnd);
void Render();

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmd, int nCmdShow)
{
    g.app = hInst;

    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
    iccex.dwSize = sizeof(iccex);
    iccex.dwICC = ICC_BAR_CLASSES|ICC_COOL_CLASSES|ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES|ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS|ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES|ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex);

    initWindow(nCmdShow);

    MSG m;
    ZeroMemory(&m, sizeof(m));
    while(m.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        Render();

        if(PeekMessage(&m, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) && !IsDialogMessage(g.wnd, &m))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&m);
            DispatchMessage(&m);
        }
    }
}

bool initWindow(int cmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("Window Party");
    wc.hInstance = g.app;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(g.app, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2));
    wc.hIconSm = wc.hIcon;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    g.wnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("Window Party"), _T("Window Party"), WS_SYSMENU|WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_OVERLAPPED, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 800, NULL, NULL, g.app, NULL);

    ShowWindow( g.wnd, cmdShow );                           // technically should be nCmdShow

    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        Init(hwnd);
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId    = LOWORD(wparam);
            int wmEvent = HIWORD(wparam);
            switch(wmId)
            {
            case IDM_FILE_CLOSE:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            case IDOK:
            case IDC_THE_BUTTON:
                {
                    MessageBox(hwnd, _T("You have pressed the button!"), _T("Congraturation"), MB_OK);
                }
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            TCHAR buff[64] = {0};
            wsprintf(buff, _T("Key Pressed: 0x%X"), (unsigned)wparam);
            MessageBox(hwnd, buff, _T("YOYOYO"), MB_OK);
            break;
        }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void Init(HWND wnd)
{
    //Creating controls
    RECT cr;
    GetClientRect(wnd, &cr);
    g.panel = CreateWindow(_T("STATIC"), NULL, WS_CHILDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE|CS_OWNDC|CS_VREDRAW|CS_HREDRAW, 0, 0, cr.right, cr.bottom-26, wnd, NULL, g.app, NULL);
    g.button = CreateWindow(_T("BUTTON"), _T("The Button"), WS_CHILDWINDOW|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON|WS_VISIBLE, cr.right-160, cr.bottom-26, 160, 26, wnd, (HMENU)IDC_THE_BUTTON, g.app, NULL);
    g.text = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("EDIT"), NULL, WS_CHILDWINDOW|ES_LEFT|WS_VISIBLE, 0, cr.bottom-26, cr.right-160, 26, wnd, NULL, g.app, NULL);

    //Setting fonts
    HFONT hf = NULL;
    hf = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(g.button, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hf, TRUE);
    SendMessage(g.text, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hf, TRUE);

    //Creating wgl context
    g.fdc = GetDC(g.panel);
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {0};
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW|PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL|PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 8;

    SetPixelFormat(g.fdc, 1, &pfd);
    g.glrc = wglCreateContext(g.fdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(g.fdc, g.glrc);

    RECT pcr;
    GetClientRect(g.panel, &pcr);
    glViewport(0, 0, pcr.right, pcr.bottom);

    glewInit();

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    UpdateWindow(wnd);
}

void Render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    SwapBuffers(g.fdc);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this in the debugger? What line does it stop on?

Comment: it doesn't stop at all, it freezes the entire computer. I could try manually breaking, but I don't thin i'm fast enough

Comment: Put breakpoints in your code and see where it stops responding. Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: I also know that it must be in the Render function because I don't get the problem if I comment out the call to it

Comment: +1 you get my 1000'th upvote. Have you resolved this problem? If so please post the answer yourself or if you have time give us a status update, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must not call `Render()` for every single window message! Only call `Render()` for [WM_PAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) messages.

Comment: But who's WM_PAINT? the Control or the whole window? and I believe that I had that originally (for the window's WM_PAINT) and I still had the same problem.

Comment: Indeed, when I add a WM_PAINT handler to my WndProc function, the problem persists

Comment: Do you call BeginPaint() and EndPaint() in your WM_PAINT handler? If not, the window will be repainted over and over again, never stopping.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a memory leak somewhere. The computer will come to a screeching stop if the PF usage gets too high.

Open up your task manager and look at the PF Usage before and then again during running the program. If it jumps up .5GB or more and keeps climbing then you've got a memory leak on your hands.

If it behaves in the manner described above the most likely culprit is that you are either making a new object (or texture) multiple times causing Windows to need to allocate more PF space for you, or you could have your VSYNC turned off.

I probably don't have to tell you what happens with a memory leak, but with the VSYNC turned off the program is going to try to run as fast as the CPU lets it. It will max out your CPU and it will do it fast.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't actually have enough time from when the program runs to when the machine becomes unresponsive. Also, I am not allocating anything in the program, even the hDC for the static control is only created once.

Comment: I was fighting something similar in my program yesterday. What I did was to only call the render event when I click within the GLcontrol. that way I can open up a Task manager and slowly step through the renders see if my render method was the problem. I.E. dont put the render method call inside any loops until you can figure out what's causing the problem.